# Remove Formula but keep data with source formatting?

Tags: excel

Remove Formula but keep data with source formatting ?

I have excel data on which couple of columns have formula. I need to remove the formula but keep data intact with formatting.

Everywhere on google below solution is given

1. Select the cells with formulas you want to remove but keep results, press Ctrl + C keys simultaneously to copy the selected cells.
2. click Home > Paste > Values

But its not keeping the source formatting like Merged cells etc.

Then instead of doing  `click Home > Paste > Values` I did `click Home > Paste > Values and Source Formatting` but it is still keeping formula

How can I remove the formula but keep data intact with source formatting ?

Update :- Screen shot based on Tim answer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

- Create a new column to the right of the column whose content and formatting (but not formula) you want to want to preserve
- Copy the column, and paste (all) into this new column.  This will bring in formatting, values, and formulas
- Then, copy the original column again, and paste this into the new column using `Paste Special`.  You may find this from the drop down menu, or using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.  In the dialog box, make sure that only the "Values" option is selected.

The basic idea is to make a carbon copy of the original column, then to wipe out the formulas only.

Comment: @ I do not see any option to select both content and formatting on dialog bog. Please see my updated post with screenshot. I can either select `Formats` or `Values` ?

Comment: @scottmiles What about the `Values and number formats` option?

Comment: @scottmiles I found a solution.  First copy all as you normally would.  Then copy and paste special with values only.

Comment: In my post i already mention the solution you posted but that is not keepng the formatting(in my case merged cell are getting unmerged again) . I am not sure what I am missing here ?

Comment: No, your question does not describe what I suggest.  I didn't test with merged cells and will do so when I get to work.

Comment: @scottmiles Then I don't have an exact answer.  I will leave this up in case it might help someone else trying to answer your question.

Comment: Not a problem Thanks.